# TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object React js material-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
 {
        title: 'Stores', field: 'Depolar',
        editComponent: props => (
          <Select
            name="Depolar"
            type="text"
            value={that.state.selectedStores}
            multiple
            input={<Input />}
            onChange={e => {

                that.setState({
                  selectedStores:e.target.value
                })
            let store=that.state.stores.find(item => !that.state.selectedStores.includes(item.Adi)

            )
              Object.keys(store.Urunler).map(function (key,index) {
                if(store.Urunler[key]){
                that.setState({
                  products:that.state.products.push(store.Urunler[key])

                 });
                }

              })
              console.log(that.state.products)






          }}
          >
            {that.state.stores.map(item=> {
              return <MenuItem value={item.Adi}>{item.Adi}</MenuItem>
            })}
          </Select>
        )
      },
      {
        title: 'Products', field: 'Urunler',
        editComponent: props => (
          <Select
            name="Urunler"
            type="text"
            value={that.state.selectedProducts}
            input={<Input />}
            multiple
            onChange={e => {               
                that.setState({selectedProducts:e.target.value})

            }}
          >
            {/* Aşağıdaki mapde hata veriyor. Objecte çevir*/}
            {that.state.products ? Object.keys(that.state.products).map(function (key,index) {
              return <div><MenuItem value={that.state.products[key].Adi}>{that.state.products[key].Adi} </MenuItem></div>
            }
            ):null}
          </Select>
        )},
```

---

getting error. I try to do multiple select and change second select's data with first Select's Onchange on material-table row.
I am using firebase.

I am taking this error when "store.Urunler" is null or undefined. and also my products doesnt list on MenuItem mean Select is Empty but state.products has data

How can i get over this error. and also i wanna add to Urunler Select an input. I know i should call function for onChanges but if it works i will do later

Answer (score 0):

```
{
        title: 'Stores', field: 'Depolar',
        editComponent: props => (
          <Select
            name="Depolar"
            type="text"
            value={that.state.selectedStores}
            multiple
            input={<Input />}
            onChange={async e => {
              let odata=[]

                this.setState({
                  selectedStores:e.target.value,
                  products:odata
                })
            let store= await that.state.stores.filter(item => (
              !that.state.selectedStores.includes(item.Adi))
        );
        console.log(store)
         this.changeProducts(store);}}
          >
            {that.state.stores.map(item=> {
              return <MenuItem value={item.Adi}>{item.Adi}</MenuItem>
            })}
          </Select>
        )
      },
      {
        title: 'Products', field: 'Urunler',
        editComponent: props => (
          <Select
            name="Urunler"
            type="text"
            value={that.state.selectedProducts}
            input={<Input />}
            multiple
            onChange={e => {               
                that.setState({selectedProducts:e.target.value})


            }}
          >
            {/* Aşağıdaki mapde hata veriyor. Objecte çevir*/}
            {that.state.products ? Object.keys(that.state.products).map(function (key,index) {
              return <div><MenuItem value={that.state.products[key].Adi}>{that.state.products[key].Adi} </MenuItem></div>
            }
            ):null}
          </Select>
        )
      },

changeProducts( store){
var that=this;
Object.keys(store).map(function (key,index) {
  let data=store[key].Urunler;
  if(data){
   that.setState({
    products:{...that.state.products,...data}

   });
  }

})
```

}

Comment: Actually selected stores using on setstate and this.state so state cant work correct. Should assign it value and change includes not !that.state.selectedStores.includes(item.Adi) to that.state.selectedStores.includes(item.Adi)